# Cast one of the operands of this integer division to a "double"

Tags: java, spring

i am getting the sonar qube warning on the below code, actually i know the solution of this but still want know if any another best way to solve that problem  ,

```
    public static ProductServiceExpenseModel createModel(ProductServiceExpense entity) {

            if (entity == null) {
                return null;
            }
            ProductServiceExpenseModel model = new ProductServiceExpenseModel();
            float cost = (float) (entity.getCost() / 100);
//Cast one of the operands of this integer division to a "double".
            model.setCost(cost);
            model.setProductName(entity.getProductName());
            model.setProductExpenseId(entity.getProductExpenseId());
            return model;
        }
```

In above method , i get the warning on `float cost = (float) (entity.getCost() / 100);` this part please let me know if there is any best approach to handle that , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the *simplest* approach would be to change `100` to `100.0`.

Comment: But just for the record: you understand that using *floating point* representation for **currency** is a huge no no no go in the real world?

Comment: @GhostCat so what do you suggest ?

Comment: Doing some research? http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13

Comment: @h36p You should  use `BigDecimal` for money. Never floating-point.

Comment: @GhostCat Thinking about Bitcons ? ;)

Comment: @SureshAtta I am working for big blue. I am only allowed to think Blockchain ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys , as i m already said i kn the the answer but still want some better approach , in this R&D i get the new thing , i definitely use it for currency Thanks ones again